# jQuery Content slider blocks responsive menu drawer

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

[The content slider blocks the menu items of my responsive site](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iYPqX.jpg)

I have used the following css to accomplish this

```css
/* http://www.menucool.com */

#sliderFrame, #sliderFrame div {
    box-sizing: content-box;
}

#sliderFrame 
{
    width:920px;
    margin:0 auto; /*center-aligned*/
    padding:20px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px #BBB;
    border:1px solid #CCC;
    background-color:#FFF;
}

#slider, #slider .sliderInner {
    width:680px;height:306px;/* Must be the same size as the slider images */
    border-radius:0px;
}

#slider {
    background-color:white;
    float:left;
    position:relative;
    transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
}

/* the link style (if an image is wrapped by a link) */
#slider a.imgLink, #slider .video {
    z-index:2;
    cursor:pointer;
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;left:0px;border:0;padding:0;margin:0;
    width:100%;height:100%;
}
#slider .video {
    background:transparent url(video.png) no-repeat 50% 50%;
}

/* Caption styles */
#slider .mc-caption {
    position:absolute;
    width:400px;
    height:auto;
    padding:10px 0;/* 10px will increase height.*/
    left:120px;
    bottom:10px;
    overflow:hidden;
    font:bold 13px/16px Arial;
    color:#069;
    text-align:center;
    background:rgba(255,255,255,0.2);
    border:1px solid rgba(255,255,255,0.3);
    border-radius: 5px;
}
#slider .mc-caption a { 
    color:#060;
}


/* ------ built-in navigation bullets wrapper ------*/
#slider .navBulletsWrapper  {
    display:none;
}

/* --------- Others ------- */

#slider img, #slider>b, #slider a>b {
    position:absolute; border:none; display:none;
}

#slider .sliderInner {
    overflow:hidden;
    position:absolute; top:0; left:0;
}

#slider>a, #slider video, #slider audio {display:none;}
#slider div {-webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);transform: translate3d(0,0,0);}



/* -- thumbnails -- */
#thumbs 
{
    float:left;
    margin-left:10px;
    width:230px;
    font:normal 11px/13px Arial;
    border-top:1px solid #CCC;
    color:#666;
}
#thumbs .thumb 
{
    border:1px solid #CCC;
    border-top:1px solid #FFF;
    padding:11px 8px;
    background:#EEE;
    cursor:pointer;
}
#thumbs .thumb-on 
{
    background:#FFF;
}

#thumbs img{border:1px solid #DDD; cursor:pointer; width:70px; height:44px;}

#thumbs .frame {float:left;padding:2px;border:1px solid #CCC;background:white;border-radius:3px;box-shadow:0 0 3px #BBB;font-size:0;line-height:0;}
#thumbs .thumb-content {float:left;width:110px;padding-left:18px;}

/* Captions in #thumbs .thumb-content */
#thumbs .thumb-content p {font-weight:bold; color:#BF5D9B; margin:0 0 3px;padding:0;}
#thumbs .thumb-on .thumb-content p {color:#BB0000;}
```

And the following html for the slider

```html
<div id="sliderFrame" style="align-content:flex-start;background-color:#93C994;">
        <div id="slider">
            <img src="img/3.jpg" alt="Caption for slide 1" />
            <img src="img/slider_jquery_responsive_slideme.jpg" alt="Caption for slide 2" />
            <a href="http://www.menucool.com"><img src="slide-3.jpg" alt="Header File" /></a>
            <img src="img/picto.png" alt="Caption for slide 3" style="height:350px;width:800px"/>
            <img src="img/3.jpg" alt="Caption for slide 4"/>
            <img src="img/slider_jquery_responsive_slideme.jpg" alt="Caption for slide 5"/>
        </div>
    </div>
```

here is the html for the menu drawer

```html
<header role="banner">
    <div id="cd-logo"><a href="#0"><img src="img/cd-logo.svg" alt="logo" onClick="#"></a></div>
      <nav class="main-nav">
   <ul><!-- insert more links here -->
                <li><a class="cd-signin" href="#0">Sign in</a></li>
    <li><a class="cd-signup" href="#0">Sign up</a></li>
   </ul>
  </nav>
 </header>
```

and its corresponding CSS

```css
/* -------------------------------- 

Main components 

-------------------------------- */
header[role=banner] {
  position: relative;
  height: 50px;
  background: #343642;
}
header[role=banner] #cd-logo {
  float: left;
  margin: 4px 0 0 5%;
  /* reduce logo size on mobile and make sure it is left aligned with the transform-origin property */
  -webkit-transform-origin: 0 50%;
  -moz-transform-origin: 0 50%;
  -ms-transform-origin: 0 50%;
  -o-transform-origin: 0 50%;
  transform-origin: 0 50%;
  -webkit-transform: scale(0.8);
  -moz-transform: scale(0.8);
  -ms-transform: scale(0.8);
  -o-transform: scale(0.8);
  transform: scale(0.8);
}
header[role=banner] #cd-logo img {
  display: block;
}
header[role=banner]::after {
  /* clearfix */
  content: '';
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  header[role=banner] {
    height: 80px;
  }
  header[role=banner] #cd-logo {
    margin: 20px 0 0 5%;
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
    -moz-transform: scale(1);
    -ms-transform: scale(1);
    -o-transform: scale(1);
    transform: scale(1);
 z-index:inherit;
  }
}

.main-nav {
  float: right;
  margin-right: 5%;
  width: 44px;
  height: 100%;
  background: url("../img/cd-icon-menu.svg") no-repeat center center;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.main-nav ul {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-100%);
  -moz-transform: translateY(-100%);
  -ms-transform: translateY(-100%);
  -o-transform: translateY(-100%);
  transform: translateY(-100%);
}
.main-nav ul.is-visible {
  -webkit-transform: translateY(50px);
  -moz-transform: translateY(50px);
  -ms-transform: translateY(50px);
  -o-transform: translateY(50px);
  transform: translateY(50px);
}
.main-nav a {
  display: block;
  height: 50px;
  line-height: 50px;
  padding-left: 5%;
  background: #292a34;
  border-top: 1px solid #3b3d4b;
  color: #FFF;
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  .main-nav {
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    background: none;
    cursor: auto;
  }
  .main-nav ul {
    position: static;
    width: auto;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
    -moz-transform: translateY(0);
    -ms-transform: translateY(0);
    -o-transform: translateY(0);
    transform: translateY(0);
    line-height: 80px;
  }
  .main-nav ul.is-visible {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
    -moz-transform: translateY(0);
    -ms-transform: translateY(0);
    -o-transform: translateY(0);
    transform: translateY(0);
  }
  .main-nav li {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 1em;
  }
  .main-nav li:nth-last-child(2) {
    margin-left: 2em;
  }
  .main-nav a {
    display: inline-block;
    height: auto;
    line-height: normal;
    background: transparent;
  }
  .main-nav a.cd-signin, .main-nav a.cd-signup {
    padding: .6em 1em;
    border: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6);
    border-radius: 50em;
  }
  .main-nav a.cd-signup {
    background: #2f889a;
    border: none;
  }
}
```

Can Anyone help me???

Comment: If you have the position as absolute  for responsive mode is better that use % for left/top instead of px

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The slider is positioned above the header because it has a higher `z-index` value. Simply give the header a higher z-index value:

```
.header {
  ...
  z-index: 10;
}
```

For more information on stacking context there is an [excellent article on mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Positioning/Understanding_z_index).